# Make PHPStorm to use PROJECT_FOLDER/phpunit.xml by default for PHPunit

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

How can I make PHPStorm to use always the `phpunit.xml` in a project's directory by default.

The variable `{PROJECT_DIRECTORY}` is not working (was only guessed)

Click Path: Default Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHP Unit

[image: Screen]

*edit*
@LazyOne commented, that the path is automatically translated. But it is not:

- Edited the default settings in some project A, select `phpunit.xml` from that project
- Opened another project
- Checked Default Settings
- The path of "some project A" is used

Comment: 1) What screen you are editing (how did you get there)? is this project-specific settings or what? 2) Use full path -- as long as path is inside project then IDE will store with variables but you will always see full/translated path

Comment: are you moving your project regularly? i just use static paths...

Comment: @LazyOne I used the global settings. What you are saying about automatic path translation is very interesting. I did not try even that.

Comment: @LazyOne Does not seem to work

Comment: What do you mean by "global"? If it is `File | Default Settings...` then yeah , it will not work. Maybe try just `./phpunit.xml` ..? Not really sure here...

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37378 - has been fixed already for [2017.2.2 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) and later releases.

Answer (score 3):

It works by typing

`$PROJECT_DIR$/phpunit.xml`

in the default project.

Verified by deleting my project's `.idea` folder - after opening, it has the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use absolute paths. PHPStorm is intelligent and stores the path relative to the project root internally. You can proof that by throwing a glance at the XML files stored in the .idea folder:

```
configuration_file_path="$PROJECT_DIR$/tests/phpunit.xml.dist"
```

...that's the relevant attribute in my case, whereas my manual configuration points to an absolute path.

Comment: I am talking about editing the `Default Settings`.. there it seems not to work